# pass html background-image from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say i have three levels hierarchy html code looking like this:

```
<section>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and i set `background-image:someImage.jpg` to the `section`, and `background:white` to the outer div. is there a way to set the same image - `someImage.jpg` as background to the inner div BUT in a way its actually showing the background from section and not just using the same image twice.
part iof the inner div is transparent and instead of seeing the white background of the outer  div i want to see the background image of the section.
assume the three elements looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this :

```
<section>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

section, #outer, #inner {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}

section {
    background: url('http://st.depositphotos.com/1907633/3138/i/950/depositphotos_31380901-Abstract-metal-molecules-medical-background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

#outer {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#inner {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77xyo575/

Answer (score 0):

Use a border for #outer rather than background, and make #inner semi-transparent. For example:

```
section {
    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
    background: url(background image) repeat center center;
}

#outer {
    border: 40px solid white;
}

#inner {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}
```

See [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/z9kh7zgw/)